# libtorque - how do i include the PBSD_status function?

Tags: c++, g++, pbs, torque

I am writing an application to test whether pbs_connect() is working or not. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "/usr/include/torque/pbs_ifl.h"
#include "/usr/include/torque/pbs_error.h"

#include <pbs_config.h>
#include "libpbs.h"

int main() {


        printf("Hello world\n");

        int server = pbs_connect("inferno.local");

        //batch_status * stat1 = pbs_statserver(server, NULL, NULL);

        pbs_errno = 0;
        batch_status * stat1 = PBSD_status(server, 21, (char *)"", NULL, NULL);

        printf("fd: %d\n", server);
        //printf("text: %s\n", stat1->text);
        //printf("name: %s\n", stat1->name);
        printf("name: %d\n", pbs_errno);

        return 0;

}

//compiled using - //g++ -o test test.c -L/usr/lib64 -ltorque
```

I get:

```
# g++ -o test test.c -L/usr/lib64 -ltorque
test.c:7:24: error: pbs_config.h: No such file or directory
test.c:8:20: error: libpbs.h: No such file or directory
test.c: In function 'int main()':
test.c:19: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
test.c:24: error: 'PBSD_status' was not declared in this scope
```

The source file that contains PBSD_status can be found here:
https://github.com/adaptivecomputing/torque/blob/4.2.7/src/lib/Libifl/PBSD_status.c

Is there something i need to include in my g++ command to get this to work? I have checked in /usr/lib64/, and there is no libpbs.h or pbs_config.h. Where would they be, if they aren't there?

Comment: Both headers should reside in the same include folder as the others (`/usr/include/torque`)

Comment: Right - they aren't there for some reason.  Is this supposed to be the case?

Comment: Do not add C tag for C++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as your headers, you're running into the difference between installed and not installed headers. Essentially, a software project doesn't install every header inside that project, only relevant ones for the API. These other two aren't in the API and therefore aren't installed. You need to reference their path.

As far as including PBSD_status() in the library, you could edit the Makefile for Libpbs to include the source file for PBSD_status() and then rebuild, or you could link to the libifl library, which is in src/lib/Libifl from the base directory for the project.

Comment: thanks for the reply - this solution does indeed work.